# Async URL Fetch and Memcache on Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is it possible to make a async url fetch on appengine and to store the rpc object in the memcache?

What I try to do is to start the asynch url fetch within a task, but I don't want the task to wait until the fetch has finished.

Therefore I tought I would just write it to memcache and access it later from outside the task, which has created the fetch.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no automated way where async Url Fetch would store data automatically to memcache on completion. You have to do it in your code, but this defeats what you are trying to do.

Also remember that memcache is volatile and it's content can be purged at any time.